# Ubuntu Linux UFW Firewall, Local Intranet Access

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firewall, intranet, ufw

At home, I have Ubuntu server with the UFW firewall. What command do I type to turn on local intranet access to my web server, but keep the outside world out from my DSL modem?

Comment: `sudo ufw allow from <ipaddress> to any port <port number>` where <ipaddress> would be your internal network and <port number> your webserver port default is 80.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess something like:  sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24 to port 80

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo ufw default deny
$ sudo ufw enable
$ sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 80
```

...where 192.168.1.* is my local NAT routing for my intranet (as in, my workstation is 192.168.1.5 and the subnet mask is 255.255.255.0.).

Comment: yes that is correct `192.168.1.0/24` you should aswell make use of `proto tcp` which will make it accept only the webserver protocol instead of all available.